# Shell to move .bad files doesn't actually move files

Tags: shell

I have small *.sh* that does login as a user and moves files that have a .bad extension to  another folder.
Here's the code:

```
su - "user"
cd..
cd input
mv *.bad /storico
```

This script runs on a virtual machine, and since it could be scheduled I would need a way to hard code the password for user "user" into the script to make it schedulable.
Since I am pretty new to these scripts I am not sure if either it's possible to set up password or not.
I was trying to fine the help for su command, but if I execute it it gives me suggestions for suspend command.

Comment: Always first test your (broken) scripts to https://shellcheck.net before asking here. `cd..` should be `cd ..`

Comment: That `su` probably doesn't do what you think it does. Which user do you think executes the `cd` and `mv`?

Comment: Since you already know the password, presumably you are authorised to run commands as that user directly. So why not just schedule the command in cron or systemd?

Comment: Thanks for the answers
su stands for switch user, so i need it to change the user that runs those commands, am i right?
I have little control over the scheduler: my client give me access just to the script itself, it's the it that handles the scheduler and its options, so i just need a way to "log" as a user and move files in the same script.
is it doable?

Comment: Did you follow the advice to use http://shellcheck.net/, btw? (If so, we should see `|| exit` suffixes on the `cd` commands).

Comment: The thing about putting `su` _in a script_ is that the commands under it don't run until after `su` exits, leaving you back in the original user account. Which user account is the script itself running as? If it's root, root can move any other user's files so you don't need to use `su` in the first place. If it's _not_ root, it can't use `su` passwordless at all.

Comment: Either way, using `su` is either unnecessary (if you're root) or it's necessary but going to fail (if you're not root). If it's the latter case, you'd be better off to use `sudo` _to start the script itself_, since you can configure in `/etc/sudoers` to give user A permission to run a specific script as user B.